# Верстка android комбинированой строки загрузки

Tags: android, android-layout

Сразу покажу о чем идет речь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать такой элемент (ListView из таких элементов, например)
С картинкой все понятно, ее можно обрезать, с текстом тоже вопросов нет. А вот с элементом "загрузки" непонятно:

1. каким образом можно делать заполнение(загрузку) зеленым цветом и какие элементы при этом использовать.
2. как при этом вставить туда еще и png

p.s. Возможно заголовок не корректный, просьба исправить если нужно!

Comment: как насчет нескольких прогрессбаров в ряд? А картинки тоже наложены сверху на них, например?

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне картинку поставить на прогресс бар? Можете в ответ  небольшой примерчик верстки для одного блока с картинкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете уложить несколько `ProgressBar` в ряд при помощи `LinearLayout`, или `RelativeLayout`.
Чтобы положить на `ProgressBar` сверху `ImageView`, положите их в `FrameLayout`, например. Чтобы изменить цвет прогресса на зеленый, сделайте так:
Создайте в папке `drawable` файл `progress.xml` с таким содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />

                <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
            </shape>
        </clip>

        <color android:color="#f58233" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />

                <solid android:color="#00ff00" />
            </shape>
        </clip>

        <color android:color="#f58233" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

И у `ProgressBar` установите атрибут:

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:visibility="visible"/>

         <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```